# What bmx logo brand is this?

Tags: identify-this-bike, bmx

[image]

What bmx logo brand is this ?

It has a lower case *b* or upside down *p* and a right-side up *p* in the shape of a rocket.

Comment: Does this logo feature elsewhere on the bike?  It might be a logo for the axle/hub maker, and not the whole bike.    I notice the rather unusual lacing of the spokes, which suggests its been redone.

Answer (score 5):

The logo on the hub in the picture matches the logo on the hub of a [Premium Products wheel](https://www.premiumbmx.com/collections/wheels-tires/products/samsara-front-wheel) See the middle picture of the three on this page.

[image]

This may be an older version of the logo. The current version is similar but rougher looking. It seems to be a face with horns.

Comment: Or ears, like a stylized wolf's head.

Comment: Great finding - I notice the spokes in your stock picture are correctly laced with a normal 3-cross format.  OP's photo looks to also be 3-cross but all the spoke heads are on the outside, leading to a "thinner" wheel and probably not as stiff or strong, which leads me to think it was rebuilt.